# .NET Core and EF relations : problem with getting data

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, blazor-webassembly

**The problem**

I have two tables with a relation; I can get any data I want from one table or the other without any problem but I can't manage getting data from both together.

The environment:

- Visual Studio 2022
- Webassembly Blazor project running on .NET 6.0
- Nuget packages

  - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.1
  - Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql
- Database MariaDb 13.3.31

The way I've constructed the data environment:

With PhpMyAdmin, I created the 2 tables with the relation.

I then launched the scaffolding command in package manager console:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=192.168.0.22;user=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;Database=MyDb;" 
         Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 
         -OutputDir Models -Context "MySqlstockDataContext" -DataAnnotations
```

After that, I created the controller with the VS2022 command "Add new Controller" and selected the "API controller with actions using Entity Framework"

My models, `DbContext` and controllers were built by the tools of VS 2022, I didn't write any code for this.

The database (a simple one with articles which can have movements (Input or Output of stock):

[image: Screenshot of the database scheme]

This is the generated code for the model class "Articles":

[Screenshot of model class Articles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnkGL.png)

This is the generated code for the model class "Mouvements":

[Screenshot of model class Mouvements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8EQa.png)

This is the generated code for the model class "DbContext":

[Screenshot of DbContext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVDfa.png)

ArticlesController:

[Screenshot of ArticlesController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qy5Y.png)

MouvementsController:

[Screenshot of MouvementsController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmC3t.png)

The Razor page:

[Screenshot for Razor page displaying the data in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppJpc.png)

What I have tried already:

In this razor page, the line

```
<td>@mouvement.IdArticleNavigation.NomArticle</td>
```

is the problem even if in the `MouvementsController`, I use

```
return await _context.Mouvements
                     .Include(e =>  e.IdArticleNavigation.NomArticle)
                     .ToListAsync();
```

instead of just

```
return await _context.Mouvements.ToListAsync();
```

To make the things go the right way, I think I should write:

```
<td>@Mouvement. Articles.NomArticle</td>
```

in the Razor page and

```
return await _context.Mouvements
                     .Include(e => e.Articles.NomArticle)
                     .ToListAsync();
```

in the MouvementsController.

But the intellisense doesn't give me this possibility. The only thing that intellisense gives me for linking the articles and the mouvements is `Include.IdArticleNavigation.NomArticle` but this doesn't work.

This is the error I see in the browser console:

> An unhandled error occurred

In the VS 2022 console, the error says

> "e.IdArticleNavigation.NomArticle" is invalid inside an include.

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdEQs.png)

I must admit I'm new to .NET Core, C#, Visual Studio and I just code for hobby. So, all the examples I saw in the Web was not very clear for me (complex developers vocabulary !)

Hope someone will be able to help me a simple way, if possible !

---

Hello Caius,
thanks a lot for this fast and sharp response which I think a understand quite good. However, maybe I don't use your advices as it should be because I can't still manage to query the two tables.
Under, you can see a picture of what I have in the Intellisense propositions when I try to reproduce the code you suggest.
[image: Picture with Intellisense propositions]
We can see than there are no propositions of properties coming from the "article" table.

To be sure my question were clear, let me tell what result I try to have : I'd like to get all the properties of the "mouvement" table and the "nom_article" property (and others also) corresponding in the "article" table. In SQL I think it would correspond to : **SELECT * FROM mouvement INNER JOIN article ON mouvement.id_article = article.id_article;** that would allow to finally get the properties to display a table like this :

id_mvt|id article|type_mvt|Qte_mvt|date_mvt|**nom_article**

[image: ERROR IN CONSOLE]
Best regards.

Comment: Do not post code as pictures - use appropriate code blocks in your question.
follow the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hello Quain, thanks for this advice. I've already tried that when I posted but the problem is that the marks to post code are { } and the code itself as many same marks (to begin and end a method for exemple). So the code posted was divided into several grey background and white background and so became difficult to read. It was my first post, I'll try to improve ! Best regards.

Comment: Try to put code in between `\`\`\`c#` and `\`\`\`` marks - this should solve the issue.
More precisely first line would be `\`\`\`C#` only,  then few lines of code, then in the separate line `\`\`\``.

Comment: In addition to not posting screenshots, whittle down your code to a small snippet that reproduces the issue. You might find the solution by whittling it down, it helps you home in on the problem area, and it makes for a much more readable question.

Comment: @Phil: if every line starts with 4 spaces, you won't have that white/grey problem. Pro tip: in your IDE, select the code, indent it once more (press tab), then copy that code. The extra indentation gives you the 4 spaces you need. If you've set indentation to 2 spaces instead of 4, obviously indent your code twice then.

Comment: Also, please don't update questions with replies to answerers. They don't even get notified of this anyway.

Comment: Thnaks Quain and Flater for all these advices. I'll take care of them ! Just to be sure : For the response I gave to Caius, I should have click on the button "Answer your question" rather than the "Edit" link ?

Comment: If you want to request clarification of advice in an answer, post a comment under the answer. If you implement the advice in an answer and then have another question, post a new question. If you realize, when implementing the advice, you have made a **minor** mistake in the question that has resulted in a minor mistake in the answer that you are capable of fixing, then edit the question, and edit the *answer*. If you are not capable of fixing the answer, comment before editing the Q. If you made a major mistake in the Q, or want to make major Q changes; accept the answer and post a new Q

Comment: If you post a new question, feel free to call the answerer to the new question by way of a link, but other people will look at and answer the new Q anyway, so you can link them to the old answer with a "I asked about X and got advice Y from [here] but now that I did that I can't..." which provides those other answerers with some additional context. In this particular case, your confusion-based typo has probably arisen because you haven't fully absorbed the advice in the answer about either Including related data into the original object graph, or making a new object with all the props you want

Comment: You posted an answer that was deleted after review (because it wasn't an answer). On that now-deleted answer I posted a comment: When you run a Select, the type of the thing that is on the right hand side of the `=>` becomes the entire type that is emitted. It's nothing to do with EF; if you had a list of people with names and ages, and you did `listOfPeople.Select(p => p.Age)` then you get an `IEnumerable<int>` (a "list/sequence/bunch" of integers) because `Age` is an `int`.

Comment: If you want to emit a `Mouvement`, you should remove the `Select` entirely - the input to `Include` is a list of Mouvements, the output from `Include` is a list of `Mouvements`, the input to `ToListAsync` is a list of `Mouvements`, the output is also, and that is what you have promised from the compiler you would return from the method when you said `public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Mouvement>>> GetMouvements` . If you go and use `Select` you're potentially changing the type of object returned from the query, to be different than what you said the method returns

Comment: ..which is in essence no different from saying `public int GetAge() { return "John"; }` -> You said you'd return an int and you put a string after the `return`. If you want to return an `IEnumerable<Mouvement>` you need to run a query that returns Mouvements. Because you say you also want the related Article, the simplest way is to ask EF for "movements include article" -> a code of `await _context.Mouvements.Include(m => m.IdArticleNavigation).ToListAsync()` does this: What the Include is doing for you is telling EF "Also download the Articles because I want to use them later".

Comment: EF will download the Article for every Mouvement, and you'll find that Article in the IdArticleNavigation property, which means when you call `var allMovemnts = await GetMouvements()` you'll have a list of Movements each with a populated IdArticleNavigation

Answer (score 1):

> "e.IdArticleNavigation.NomArticle" is invalid inside an include.

You're supposed specify a *navigation property* inside an Include, not a simple property

One Article has many Movement. If you want to access an Article from a Movement you use its nav prop:

```
myMovement.IdArticleNavigation //an article
```

EF performs joins when it sees you navigate around the objects graph:

```
context.Movements.Select(m => new { m.MovementName, m.IdArticleNavigation.ArticleName });
```

Because you've accessed a property of a related entity in a Select, EF will automatically create a JOIN in the sql to get the related Article for each Movement so it can access the related data

It does a similar thing if you navigate around in a Where clause

We use `Include` to tell EF to perform JOINs even if we don't use the related data in the where/select. It's like saying "I want all the movements where... and their related articles because later in the client side code I will use some article properties"

But be clear: you don't specify the properties of an article that you later want to use, you just specify the article and EF will download the whole thing

```
var helloMovement = context.Movements
  .Include(m => m.IdArticleNavigation)
  .First(m => m.MovementName == "hello");
```

Without the Include, `helloMovement.IdArticleNavigation` would be null

If you want only certain props (for example you know that every Article has a 5 megabyte json column and you don't want to download it) you can use the anonymous type pattern I mentioned above in the "navigating around in a select" - the generated sql in that case will only mention the article name and movement name

---

Edit

> We can see than there are no propositions of properties coming from the "article" table.

I'm starting to understand the disconnection between the way you view tables, SQL, relations, EF and object graphs

> To be sure my question were clear, let me tell what result I try to have : I'd like to get all the properties of the "mouvement" table and the "nom_article" property (and others also) corresponding in the "article" table.

> In SQL I think it would correspond to : SELECT * FROM mouvement INNER JOIN article ON mouvement.id_article = article.id_article;

Yes, but what you need to appreciate is that SQL produces rectangular blocks of data and EF/C# produces object graphs that are more like a *tree*

Let's have some simple SQL tables:

```
People
Id, Name, Age
1, John, 27
2, Mary, 23

Skills
Id, PersonId, Description
1, 1, Stonework
2, 1, Welding
3, 2, Carpentry
4, 2, Plumbing
```

If you join these you get a rectangle block of data

```
Id, Name, Age, Id, PersonId, Description
1, John, 27, 1, 1, Stonework
1, John, 27, 2, 1, Welding
2, Mary, 23, 3, 2, Carpentry
2, Mary, 23, 4, 2, Plumbing
```

This is what SQL does - it repeats the people rows because they each have 2 skills

EF doesn't do this. You have some Person that has a List of Skills:

```
{ name: John, age: 27, skills: [ { description: stonework }, { description: welding } ] }
{ name: Mary, age: 23, skills: [ { description: carpentry }, { description: plumbing } ] }
```

It's more like a tree, or a graph. There is one person object and there are two skills objects. One of the things EF has to do if it does joins is dedupe all the multiple Johns that come back so you only get one Person, and the Person has 2 Skills. Each Skill links back to the Person too so you could have a Person who has a Skill and the Skill has a Person (the same Person as we started with) ..

You could write a code like:

```
myPerson.Skills.First().Person.Skills.First().Person.Skills.First().Person.Skills.First().Person.Skills.First().Person.Skills.First().Person.Skills.First().Person.Skills.First().Person.Skills.First();
```

The graph just goes round and round. Skills is a List, the First entry is a Skill, that has a Person, that has Skills, the first of which is...

EF's job is to watch you navigating around this graph of linked entities and form SQLs that will allow it to retrieve data to populate the graph to support your navigating of it

When you do:

```
context.People.Where(p => p.Name == "John");
```

You get John. His Skills list will be empty, even if he has Skills in the DB. EF didn't see you use Skills so it doesn't bother joining it in. It makes the minimum number of joins it has to to pull just the data you seem to want to use

If you said:

```
context.People.Where(p => p.Skills.Any(s => s.Description== "Carpentry"));
```

EF would do the join (actually, it'd probably use an EXISTS, but let's pass over that for now) so it can get the WHERE to work (it needs the related data) but it wouldn't select the Skills, because again it doesn't look like you need them

If you mentioned in a Select:

```
context.People.Select(p => new { p.Name, p.Skills });
```

EF can see you using Skills, so it'll JOIN it so it can deliver you what you've asked for (an anonymous type of the person name and their Skills)

If you didn't mention Skills:

```
context.People.Select(p => p);
```

Then you'd get all the People, but all their Skills collections would be empty, because EF can't see you wanting to use them

If you told EF you wanted the Skills too (because you plan to use them some other time):

```
context.People.Include(p => p.Skills);
```

Then you'd get all the People objects and their Skills collections would be populated with skills

---

Now let's go back to the rectangular blocks of data in SQL, and the graphs in EF

```
SELECT * FROM people JOIN skills on people.Id = skills.peopleId
```

Yes, joining skills and people will let you "just use the names of skills/people in the select" :

```
SELECT name, Description FROM people JOIN skills on people.Id = skills.peopleId
```

but really you're *supposed to* use the table name (or alias), so SQL still has this notion of "remembering where the data came from":

```
SELECT people.name, skills.Description FROM people JOIN skills on people.Id = skills.peopleId
```

---

Object graphs in C# don't let you just "type random property names" - you have to "specify where the data comes from"

```
myPerson.Skills.First().Description.Substring(2);
```

Now, quick chat about LINQ inputs and outputs

```
context.People                     //People is a list of Person
  .Where(p => p.Name == "John")    //Where outputs a list of Person
  .Where(p => p.Age == 27)         //Where outputs a list of Person
```

Some things in LINQ change what you get out, others don't. When you chain method calls like A.B.C.D you have to bear in mind that what A outputs is what is fed into B, and what B outputs is what is fed into C.

Some things output a similar thing to what is fed in:

```
Where - called on a list of X, produces a list of X
```

Some things slightly change what comes out:

```
First - called on a list of X, produces a single X
```

Some things drastically change what comes out:

```
Select - called on a list of X, produces a list of Y
```

Include is one of those things that doesn't change what comes out. You have:

```
context.Skills               //a list of Skill
  .Include(s => s.Person)    //essentially still a list of Skill
```

Including the Person doesn't magically cause some different kind of object to come out, from the list of Skills that were fed in. When you say `Select` after `Include` you're *still selecting from a list of skills*

```
context.Skills               //a list of Skills
  .Include(s => s.Person)    //essentially still a list of Skill
  .Select(s => ...           //s is a Skill
```

For every Skill in the list, if you want to reach to the Person with the skill, you have to navigate there:

```
context.Skills               //a list of Skills
  .Include(s => s.Person)    //essentially still a list of Skill
  .Select(s => s.Person.Name)//s is a Skill, with a Person property that is a Person, that has a Name property
```

You have to do this, because this is how object graphs work in C# - they don't work like that possibility in SQL where you can just start mentioning names of columns after joining them in; you always have to be specific how you get to some property in C#

You could create an anonymous type that has all the properties you want:

```
context.Skills               
  .Include(s => s.Person)    
  .Select(s => new { PersonName = s.Person.Name, SkillDesc = s.Description})
```

This produces a new object, not a person, not a skill, but a temporary holder with just a `string PersonName` and a `string SkillDesc` properties. If you fed *that* into another Select, *then* you you would be looking at a changed set of objects that have those properties (and all the other properties of your Person/Skill are lost)

```
context.Skills               
  .Include(s => s.Person)    
  .Select(s => new { PersonName = s.Person.Name, SkillDesc = s.Description})
  .Select(at => at.PersonName)
```

This is like doing the following SQL:

```
SELECT PersonName 
FROM
  (
    SELECT people.name as PersonName, skills.Description as SkillDesc
    FROM people JOIN skills on people.Id = skills.peopleId
  ) at
```

> that would allow to finally get the properties to display a table like this :

```
id_mvt|id article|type_mvt|Qte_mvt|date_mvt|nom_article
```

Hopefully you're now up on what you need to do.. When you start from

```
 context.Movements
```

and you let EF see you using properties from Article:

```
 context.Movements
   .Where(m => ...)      //Movements in, Movements out
   .Select(m => new {    //Movements in, new anonymous object out
     m.IdMvt,
     m.IdArticle,
     ...
     m.IdArticleNavigation.NomArticle
   });
```

Remember; there's no Include necessary here, because you're selecting the related data (but you have to navigate to it via a Movement!)

You could also do:

```
var x = context.Movements
   .Include(m => m.IdArticleNavigation)
   .Where(m => ...)      //Movements in, Movements out
   .ToList();            //Movements in, Movements out
```

This produces a list of movements *with fully populated IdArticleNavigation* properties which are the related Articles. You could then do

```
x.First()               //a Movement
  .IdArticleNavigation  //the Article related to the first Movement
      .Nom              //the name of the Article
```

Comment: Sorry for making an answer to Caius in my own question (what makes Caius not informed regarding to the comment I received  from Flater !

Comment: *We can see than there are no propositions of properties coming from the "article" table* - that's because you haven't navigated to it yet. Type `e.IdArticleNavigation.SOMETHING`. When you start with `Movements` you can Include X, Y or Z, but it always comes back to `Movements`. `Movements.Include(x).Include(y).Include(z)` can be done, but x/y/z must be navigation properties on/accessible from Movements. If you want to chain on, you can use ThenInclude, but if you're pressing `.` after including `x` you don't see properties form X imported into Movements; you still have to navigate to them

Comment: @Phil I've made an edit

Comment: Caius, I've made an answer but I'm not sur that you are notified without a comment.

Comment: Caius, I'm sorry but the explainations seems clear to me but I can't still get the datas from the two tables. I wonder if the problem comes from the code.

Comment: Caius, I'm sorry but the explainations seems clear to me but I can't still get the datas from the two tables. I wonder if the problem comes from the code.  .Include(e => e.IdArticleNavigation) produces an unhandler error in the browser and  .Include(e => e.Articles) or  .Include(e => e.Article) are not accepted by VS intellisense.

Comment: What does "produces an error in the browser" mean? What error message?

Comment: The message appears in a yellow bar : "An unhandeled error has occured". In the VS console, the message is the same but of course with long debbuging informations (which I don't understand the technical meaning). I put a copy of the console message (picture) at the end of my first post (upper in this page, just above "Best regards").

Comment: I've just made a search on the Web about this "Json cycle error" and found a working solution : Adding "services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
                x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles)" in the ConfigureSevices of Startup.cs. It works well but I don't know if it's a good solution because I don't understand what this code means !

Comment: Yes, that's what happens when you serialize an entity framework graph, because the graph is two-directional (it has cycles in). You have a Movement X, which has an Article Y. The Article Y has Movements, one of which is Movement X, which has Article Y, which has Movements one of which is X, which has... And it goes round and round. As the serializer is trying to write everything into a string it ends up going round and round this cycle. I mentioned it above when I said `myPerson.Skills.First().Person.Skills.First().Person.Skills.First().Person.Skills.First()...`

Comment: This doesn't happen if you use different objects - we usually don't serialize our EF database entities out to the front end - instead we map them to some limited set of entities (dtos or viewmodels depending who you ask) that are designed for the front end to use and has only the data the front end needs. These object graphs don't usually have cycles. All this, however, is unrelated to the original question of loading related data, so it's probably the time where you should accept an answer to this question and if you get a different problem in future with this project, ask a new question.

Comment: Caius, effectively, one problem may comes from many causes (I'm used to this with car mechanics in which I'm better than programming !). Anyway, great thanks for all the time given to solve this problem, wtith extra explainations.